# SQL join: avoid duplicate entries while joining two tables?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have two tables, A and B, and I am trying to select rows from A based on a join query.
I am getting some records from these tables, but there are some duplicate entries.  How should I filter this query to avoid duplicate rows? For now, I'm doing it via Java code by putting these into a HashSet.

Comment: "I am getting some records from these tables but which has some duplicate entries how to filter this query itself" hardly constitutes a good description of your problem.

Comment: Could you show us your current query?

Comment: i m simply asking , is there any way to filterout duplicate entries from a join query?

Comment: Then, the best answer you're going to get is "Yes"

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, You should invest some time in asking the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keyword DISTINCT is used to eliminate duplicate rows from a query result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON ...
```

However, you can sometimes (possibly even 'often', but not always) avoid the need for it if the tables are organized correctly and you are joining correctly.

To get more information, you are going to have to ask your question more clearly, with concrete examples.

Answer (score 4):

You must explain table structure but I can understand your question. You may use this query:

```
select a.atribute1, a.atribute2, b.atribut1, b.atribut2
  from a inner join b
    on a.primarykey = b.foreign_key
 where a.atribute = ""
 group by a.atribute2, b.atribute2
```

You can use `a.atribute = ""` for validation.

Use `group by a.atribute2, b.atribute2` if you want the row in one group of this attribute.